# Autocompletefb working fine in mozilla but not in IE7

Tags: facebook, autocomplete, internet-explorer-7, debugging, mozilla

Could you please suggest a debugging tool for browser issues?

Answer (score 0):

Use IE developer tools. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en